# Spring MVC integration with Tiles

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

I am using tiles as a viewResolver with Spring 3 MVC. I have a home page which needs to be invoked for which there wont be any controller. I found the syntax for mapping URLs without the controller for other view resolver. How can i achieve this with the tiles view resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understand you want to serve a page as static source(without interact controller) if so this process doesnt change with view resolver you  should use resource mapping tag

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```